# Show specific places using Google Maps, but with code

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

I am developing an App with kotlin, in it I implement Google maps, and its API, or I get the location and everything, but what I require is that I filter a specific type of place, it will be predefined in the App, and that it works as When doing a search, for example with Hospitals, and showing the Hospitals that are nearby, how would you do this search from code?

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient : FusedLocationProviderClient

private lateinit var lastLocation: Location

companion object {
    private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
}

private lateinit var map: GoogleMap

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
}



/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    map = googleMap



    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
    map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

    setUpMap()

}



private fun setUpMap(){
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return
    }

    map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID




    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener (this){location:Location ->
        lastLocation = location
        val currentLatLong = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLong, 16f))


    }
}

override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?): Boolean =  false
```

This is the code that I have so far, and it is the one that controls everything on the map

I require you to show me the sites like this.

I have searched "hospitals" and it shows me with markers the hospitals in the area, I require something like this to be seen in the App
[search hospitals in Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoaAI.jpg)